# determine the smallest degree of the polynomial

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, continuity

Let be $q:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a polynomial of degree n and consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by

$f(x) =\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if}\quad x\le 0\\[2ex]
q(x),  & \text{if}\quad 0<x<1\\[2ex]
x, & \text{if } \quad x\ge1
\end{cases}$

Determine  $\quad q\quad$as small as possible (lowest possible degree of the polynomial $q(x)$ ) so that f is differentiable for all $x\in \mathbb{R} $

Comment: What is a "small" polynomial of degree $n$?

Comment: lowest possible degree of the polynomial

Comment: Ok, so how do you want to approach this question? Do you want to try $n=2$?

Comment: $n = 2$ will not in work, I suspect . . .

Comment: You mean $f(x)$, not $f(n)$, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the following constraints on $q(x)$:

$q(0) = q'(0) = 0, \tag 1$

from $f(x) = 0$ for $x \le 0$;

$q(1) = q'(1) = 1, \tag 2$

from $f(x) = x$ for $x \ge 1$;

if we write

$q(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d, \tag 3$

then

$q(0) = 0 \Longrightarrow d = 0; \tag 4$

$q'(0) = 1 \Longrightarrow c = 0; \tag 5$

$q(1) = 1 \Longrightarrow a + b + c + d = 1; \tag 6$

$q'(1) = 1 \Longrightarrow 3a + 2b + c = 1; \tag 7$

using (4) and (5) in (6) and (7) we see that

$a + b = 1; \tag 8$

$3a + 2b = 1; \tag 9$

we see that

$a = -1, \; b = 2; \tag{10}$

thus

$q(x) = -x^3 + 2x^2; \tag{11}$

also,

$q'(x) = -3x^2 + 4x; \tag{12}$

it is easy to see that $q(x)$ as in (11) satisfies (1) and (2).

A quadratic won't work; try setting

$q(x) = ax^2 + bx + c \tag{13}$

and see what happens.  I leave it to you.